# Size of an intersection with a randomly chosen subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm hoping for some help with this excericse in probability.

> Let $V$ be a set and let $V'$ be a randomly chosen subset of $V$ such that each element belongs to $V'$ with probability $p$.
>
> Now, let $S \subset V$  such that $|S|= x$, what's the probability that $|V' \cap S|<x/3$?
>
> It might be easier to assume that $p=1/2$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's the probability of $<x/3$ successes in $x$ independent trials with probability of success $p$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: It will depend on how $V'$ is chosen: if the inclusion/exclusion of each element of $V$ is independent of the others then you may get a different result compared with choosing a fraction $p$ of the elements of $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted by user31373 in a comment, this is the probability of $\lt x/3$ successes in $x$ independent trials with probability of success $p$, which is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil\frac x3\right\rceil-1}\binom xkp^k(1-p)^{x-k}\;.
$$